# Error while using HttpClientBuilder to replace DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, web-services, httpclient

I was using deprecated DefaultHttpClient to replace that I followed the tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/the-type-defaulthttpclient-is-deprecated/ but I am getting an error. If I replace HttpClientBuilder.create().build() with new DefaultHttpClient() the error is resolved.

MainActivity.java

```
private void registerInBackground(final String username) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regId = gcm.register(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                        + regId);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

                HttpClient httpClient=HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                String authenticationURL = "http://192.168.100.16:8080/NotificationWebService/saveDeviceID?userName="+username+"&deviceId="+regId+"&idType=ANDROID&callBack=jsonCallback";
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "URL "
                        + authenticationURL);
                HttpGet authenticationGetRequest = new HttpGet(authenticationURL);
                HttpResponse authenticationResponse = httpClient.execute(authenticationGetRequest);

                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                        + authenticationResponse);
                //storeRegistrationId(context, regId);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
            }
            Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

logs.txt

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
```

Comment: Why not using `HttpURLConnection ` instead of `HttpClient ` ?

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippet of that to hit a webservice in android using that

Comment: See [Android POST and GET Request using HttpURLConnection Tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-post-and-get-request-using-httpurlconnection/)

Comment: Thanx .!! exactly what  I wants

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code, i think it will help you :

https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-post-and-get-request-using-httpurlconnection/